# Horizontal scroll with a full background image

Tags: html, css

I want a fullwidth background (with horizontal scroll) for a project that I'm working on at the moment.

I've added the following code to set the background:

```
.street {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    background: url('../img/street.svg') no-repeat left;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -2;
}
```

That works, but then I've had a new problem, because of the background-size: cover the image only shows a part of it.

The user has to scroll horizontally, so that he or she can see the whole street image. My question is: How van I fix that? (I've already searched on the internet and maybe it is a really simple solution, so sorry for asking :))

[What I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3g3xG.png)
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `background-size: contain`?

Comment: take, `background-size: 100%;`

Comment: @Sravan isnt it better to use `background-size: 100% 100%`  (ignoring the fact that i prefer `contain`)?

Comment: @JoseRuiSantos Yes I did! But then it showed the full image, but it didn't made it fullwidth...

Answer (score 0):

use, `background-size: 100% 100%;` this will fill your entire DIV with complete image.

```
.street {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    background: url('../img/street.svg') no-repeat left;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -2;
}
```

**Here is the difference:**

- **Percentage:**  Sets the width and height of the background image in percent of the parent element. The first value sets the width, the
  second value sets the height. If only one value is given, the second
  is set to "auto".
- **Cover:**   Resize the background image to cover    the entire container, even if it has to stretch the image or cut a    little bit
  off one of the edges.
- **Contain:** Resize the    background image to make sure the image is fully visible

[Here is a good explanation for the same](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

Comment: w3schools is a terrible site and you should not link to it to support your answers. use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/ instead..

Comment: @BhuwanBhatt, W3schools is a good site for basic `html` and `css`. It might not have depth as `mozilla` but, for basics like these, it is fine

Comment: @Sravan When I add that the image goes full size, but not full size of the screen..

Comment: This is not an ideal solution. This stretches the image.